# Setting the pipe so that it does not put . automatically as first argument

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

While using the pipe the lhs is automatically placed as the first argument of the rhs. This leads to the fact that both codes are equal:

```
library(dplyr)
1:10 %>% mean(na.rm = TRUE) # same as...
1:10 %>% mean(., na.rm = TRUE)
```

I just come into a situation where I needed the pipe to stop automatically using `.` as the first argument (as asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76154658/1nrow-cant-refer-to-former-defined-object-with-pipe?noredirect=1#76154686)). And in fact I *never* do `1:10 %>% mean(na.rm = TRUE)`, i.e. I always explicitly supply the first argument with `.` while using the pipe. Therefore I am wondering whether it is possible to prevent the pipe from always automatically put `.` as the first argument.

This means `%>%` should behave by default as if the rhs was in curly brackets:

```
1:10 %>% {mean(na.rm = TRUE)} 
# Returns an error since x is missing. This is expected! Again: I
# want %>% not to automatically provide the first argument with .
```

There is a similiar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38717657/use-pipe-without-feeding-first-argument). But in my case I want `%>%` by default prevent from this behavior.

Comment: I don't think so.  You could write your own pipe operator ...

Comment: Hmm this is *basically* a duplicate of the linked question. But in case the other question hadn't made it clear yet: the only way to do this with the ‘magrittr’ pipe is to use `{…}`. If you do not like this you will have to write your own pipe operator (which, if you always want to pass `.` explicitly, isn’t hard).

Comment: @KonradRudolph "(which, if you always want to pass . explicitly, isn’t hard)": Yes I want to and I do so (as stated in the question). And yes, I wanted to see how "to write your own pipe operator"

Comment: You can use `|>`, which uses `_` (with a much more limited scope) and never uses `.`

Comment: @r2evans But using `1:10 |> mean(na.rm = TRUE)` works although first argument is not provided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pipe that explicitly replaces a placeholder can be implemented (fairly) straightforwardly since the base R function `substitute` implements the bulk of this. The one caveat is that `substitute` expects an unquoted expression, so we need to work around that, and we obviously need to evaluate the resulting expression:

```r
`%>%` = function (lhs, rhs) {
  subst = call('substitute', substitute(rhs), list(. = lhs))
  eval.parent(eval(subst))
}
```

Here I am reusing the `%>%` operator but if you are concerned about conflicts with ‘magrittr’ you may obviously use another operator, e.g. `%|%`.

```r
1:5 %>% sum(na.rm = TRUE, .) %>% identity()
# Error in identity() : argument "x" is missing, with no default

1:5 %>% sum(na.rm = TRUE, .) %>% identity(.)
# [1] 15
```

The above works by *replacing* each occurrence of `.` in the RHS with the value provided by the LHS. That is, during evaluation `.` *is not a name*. This is usually the *expected* and *desired* semantic. However, it means that you cannot assign *to* `.` inside the RHS (including calling replacement functions), because `.` is not a name.

So something like `{names(.) = "foo"; .}` does not work.

We can fix this with a different implementation, which does not replace `.` with the LHS but rather *injects* a definition of `.` into the environment where the RHS is evaluated:

```r
`%>%` = function (lhs, rhs) {
  eval_env = new.env(parent = parent.frame())
  eval_env$. = lhs
  eval(substitute(rhs), envir = eval_env)
}
```

Now we can use `.` as a name in assignments:

```
1 %>% {names(.) = "foo"; .}
# foo
#   1
```

*However*, some other things no longer work, because we now evaluate the expression in a different environment:

```r
1:5 %>% assign("x", .)
x
# Error: object 'x' not found
```

… whereas this *did* work with the first pipe implementation. We *could* make it work again by injecting `.` directly into the calling environment but this messes with the user environment and I would *strongly* discourage doing that.<sup>1</sup>

Instead, if you want to do things like calling `assign` within a pipeline expression, be explicit into which environment you want to assign (i.e. pass something like `envir = the_environment` to `assign`).

---

<sup>1</sup> You *could* avoid messing with the user environment by carefully preserving the user state and cleaning up afterwards; but this leads to a much more complex (and error-prone) implementation:

```r
`%>%` = function (lhs, rhs) {
  caller = parent.frame()
  
  if (exists('.', envir = caller, inherits = FALSE)) {
    stored_dot = caller$.
    on.exit({caller$. = stored_dot})
  } else {
    on.exit(rm(., envir = caller))
  }
  
  caller$. = lhs
  eval.parent(substitute(rhs))
}
```

(This is a simplified implementation; **do not use it!** In particular, it fails if `.` refers to an active binding in the parent environment. We could add handling for active bindings — with difficulty — but it’s entirely likely that I forgot some other edge case; like I said, this is error-prone.)

Comment: Interestingly it is not for all code same as `{rhs}`. Example: `data.frame(1:10, row.names = letters[1:10]) %newpipe% rownames(.)  <- 1:nrow(.); .` does not work but `data.frame(1:10, row.names = letters[1:10]) %>% {rownames(.)  <- 1:nrow(.); .}` does.

Comment: Wow there is a *lot* to learn for me from this answer! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2):

As in the comment was *define your own function*.
Here `.` is set to the value of the lhs in a new environment where the rhs is evaluated.

```
`:=` <- function(lhs, rhs) eval(substitute(rhs), list(. = lhs))

1:10 := mean(., na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 5.5

1:10 := mean(na.rm = TRUE)
#Error in mean.default(na.rm = TRUE) : 
#  argument "x" is missing, with no default

data.frame(1:10, row.names = letters[1:10]) := {rownames(.)  <- 1:nrow(.); .}
#   X1.10
#1      1
#2      2
#3      3
#4      4
#5      5
#6      6
#7      7
#8      8
#9      9
#10    10

1 := {names(.) = "foo"; .}
#foo
#  1

1 %>% assign("x", .)
x
# Error: object 'x' not found
```

The used operator influences the evaluation. See: [Same function but using for it the name %>% causes a different result compared when using the name :=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76155705).

```
`%|%` <- `:=`

1 := . + 2 := . * 3
#[1] 9

1 %|% . + 2 %|% . * 3
#[1] 7
```

Comment: Please, *please*, for all that's holy **please** don't use string quotes to make syntactic names. R should not allow this, it is a huge flaw in the language and it terminally confuses beginners. Use backtick quotes. Besides this it would be good if you discussed the caveats of this rather hacky solution.

Comment: Huh ... perhaps there are other operators one could define besides `:=`? It's used extensively in `data.table` (and even defined in `rlang`), there are likely collisions here (though I recognize the question is mostly dplyr).

Comment: Nice edit, thanks. For the sake of completeness, one could also name it `%cecinestpasunpipe%` ;-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Would you mind when I also ask a SO question about string quotes and syntactic names?

Comment: @GKi Please go ahead. But the short answer is that `"a" = 1` is valid R and treats `"a"` as a variable name (?!?!). but `b = "a"` does *not* treat `"a"` as a variable name. **This is idiotic**. There's really not much more to say on the topic.

Comment: I have asked a question to allow finding this topic easier than in a comment. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76342471